# fatal: Unable to create 'D:/testgit/.git/index.lock': File exists

Tags: git, github, git-bash

Пытаюсь добавить несколько новых проектов. Раньше всё закидывалось, а сейчас Git Bash выбивает ошибку, какую бы команду я не вводил, например, `git add .` или `git commit -m "new"`. Не могу понять, что не так.

> fatal: Unable to create 'D:/testgit/.git/index.lock': File exists. If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git process is running and remove the file manually to continue.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прочитайте. Переведите. Выполните что просят.

Comment: Скриншот стоило бы заменить текстом ошибки.

Comment: На все команды 
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "new"
fatal: Unable to create 'D:/testgit/.git/index.lock': File exists.

If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a
git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git
process is running and remove the file manually to continue.

Comment: @Кнопкатык, когда у меня Git выдаёт ошибки, я не перевожу, а сразу вбиваю их текст в Гугл. На момент написания комментария всегда удавалось найти вопросы людей с аналогичными ошибками Git, в основном, на англоязычном SO, — и это мне помогало. Владимир, Вы пробовали  [**этот вариант**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7860765/5951529)?

Comment: @СашаЧерных дело в том, что там **прямым текстом написано, что делать**.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку. Так и сделал. В течении 30 минут нашел решение и исправил проблему)

Comment: $ rm -f ./.git/index.lock    
$ rm -Force ./.git/index.lock    
$ git status    
$ git add .    
$ git status   
$ git commit -m "new work"   
$ git push test master (если не работает тогда) $ git push -f

Comment: @VladimirLebedev По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 4):

Переведу последнее предложение ошибки:

> Удостоверьтесь, что другие процессы Git не запущены и удалите файл вручную для продолжения работы.

Не выходя из Git Bash, файл можно удалить [командой `rm`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rm) (ключ `-f` лучше не использовать, поскольку если где-то будет допущена опечатка, не будет выведен текст ошибки). В Вашем случае вписываем следующее:

`$ rm ./.git/index.lock`

Файл `index.lock` удалён, можно продолжать работу.